# Problem with adding multiple tables from imported text file

Tags: list-manipulation

Im having problems with performing operations on imported files and it is outlined as follows:

$1.$ Because of memory constraints on my computer, I used export that saves each iteration into a text file. Suppose i use `Exp(-I x),` I have the following code for exporting the file:

```
Table[f = OpenAppend["test.txt"];
  WriteString[f, ExportString[{{N[x], N[Exp[-I x]]}}, "Table"], 
   "\n"];
  Close[f];, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];
```

$2.$ I also use the same method to export another table. For example, `Cos[10x]`

```
Table[g = OpenAppend["test1.txt"];
  WriteString[g, ExportString[{{N[x], N[Cos[10 x]]}}, "Table"], 
   "\n"];
  Close[g];, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];
```

$3.$ I want to import these two data and either add or subtract only the second column of the two tables while maintaining the value of the first column.

I don't know how to do the third part. How do I do this in Mathematica? Thanks in advance.